# How to implement timeouts for multiple BitTorrent announce requests?

Tags: java, multithreading, bittorrent

I am trying to make a BitTorrent client just for learning purposes. I will first explain what I have done till now.

I have created a thread pool whose size is the number of available processors. Now each torrent file is executed on a separate thread. I get the list of tracker URLs from each torrent file and use java NIO to send connect requests. I assume that I send all the connect requests at approximately the same time because I am just looping the list of URLs and sending requests. So instead of maintaining timeouts for each URL, I am starting the timer when the first request is sent. When the timer times out, I resend connect request to all the URLs which have not responded. (Here, for timer, I calculate the `interval` and keep track of starting time `startTime`. I loop until `currentTimeMillis()` exceeds `startTime+interval`. Inside loop I use `selector.select()` to select `channels` that are ready. When the loop exits, I resend connect request to all channels that did not respond. I did not use `Timer` and `ScheduledExecutorService` because I thought that this may cause number of threads to explode. I am already using one thread per file. Correct me on this and suggest better approaches).

The main problem comes while sending announce requests. I may receive connect response at any point of time, at which point I should send the announce request and start a timer, and resend the request if it times out. Currently for each connect response, I submit a `Runnable` task to thread pool which handles sending of announce request. So I am using one thread for each announce request-response cycle. So if I have many torrent files and each file has at least 5 tracker URLs, will this not create performance issue? What is a better way to make this thing work? It would be very enlightening if someone can throw some light on how torrent clients handle so many files and so many request response cycles at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit to using nio or a selector based library like netty is to allow you to multiplex multiple network connections into a single object and only wait on that object. Multiplex definitionally means [comprising several interleaved parts](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multiplex). And in this case you are weaving together multiple network connections, which previously would require individual threads to wait on, into a single conceptual object ([Selector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html)) which only requires a single thread to wait on. In your case you could weave together the entirety of your network connections into a single Selector and wait on that in a single thread. In this way there would be no proliferation of threads. Re-architecting your system in this way may require some more bookkeeping for each connection which previously would be local to the thread that was tasked with handling that connection.

Additionally do not use System#currentTimeMillis for calculating time difference, use System#nanoTime instead as it won't be affected by any changes to the system's time.

Comment: How do I handle timeout for each connection in nio?